# CakePHP postLink() and FormProtectionComponent

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to user CakePHP FormHelper::postLink() with the FormProtectionController and I get the following error:

`_Token was not found in request data`

Can postLink() be used when FormProtection is on?

Thanks,